# Is there a codeigniter equivalent of pear mdb2->fetchall()?

Tags: codeigniter

Is there a codeigniter equivalent of pear mdb2->fetchall() ?

[mdb2->fetchall()](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Result_Common.html#methodfetchAll) returns all the db rows in one statements, so you don't have to do $query->result() iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$query->result_array() gives you the complete array only.  Its not clearly documented thats why you might have got confused.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/database/results.html